# How can I draw continuous line chart with wpf toolkit.

Tags: wpf, charts, line, toolkit

How can I draw continuous line chart with wpf toolkit. for example heart rate chart.But I can use both android and windows 8 this chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some 3rd party libraries on the internet. If you google it you'll find a lot. Unfortunately (as far as i know) wpf is not supported on Android platform. So for android, I cannot help.

But, if you want to do it in the "hard way" here is a starting point: Wpf is very good at graphics. Even with the low resource (cpu,gpu,memory) devices, its performance is very good. In one of my projects I needed a continious line chart. In my scenario I have a stream of data points of 2. First one is BPM and second one is IBI. I wanted to show BPM as area graph and on top IBI as line. Here is an image:

[image: Chart Graph]

I made this as a user control. It contains a Canvas for chart, Textblocks for information. The controls are laid on a grid. For layout i'll not provide information while the topic is creating a chart.

The canvas will represent chart. Green, yellow, and red vertical lines are BPM values and blue (aqua) line is IBI value. Thus I have two series. Canvas width is my window for data points. Once the window is full then it starts to scroll continiously. To achive this each serie has a queue.

```
Queue<int> beatsColl, ibisColl;
```

If each line's stroke width is 2 pixels then Queue length `queueSize` is `canvas.width / 2`. Queue is a collection works with FIFO principle. Thus this gives us a walking view of lines.

When a new data is arrived we need to calculate the length of line. Which is: current value / Maximum value in the Queue. Then reverse it because we want to draw the line from bottom to up.

```
double lineLength = 1 - ( currentValue / maxValue );
double y1 = canvas.ActualHeight;
double y2 = y1 * lineLength; //to calculate coordinates.
```

The X1 and X2 coords are calculated in steps of: `canvas.ActualWidth / line stroke width` Then we can create line:

```
//... for each points in Queue
// i is the nTH value of Queue 
double xX = canvas.ActualWidth - ( i * lineWidth ); 
Line l = new Line() {
    Stroke = selectiveBrush,
    StrokeThickness = lineWidth,
    X1 = xX,
    X2 = xX,
    Y1 = y1,
    Y2 = y2
};
//then add the line to the canvas
canvas.Children.Add(l);
```

Don't forget to clear the canvas before adding new Queue points and try to update Queues like this:

```
void putB( int b ) {
    beatsColl.Enqueue( b );
    if (beatsColl.Count > queueSize)
        beatsColl.Dequeue();
}
```

`queueSize` is a seperate int calculated as described above.